# preimage of limsup and limsup of preimage

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $(X_n)_{\geq 1}$  be a sequence of random variables. I'm wondering what's the relationship between $\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{m\geq n} \{X_m\geq t\}$ and $\{limsup_{n\to \infty}X_n\geq t\}$. Does one contain the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y_n:=\sup_{m\ge n}X_m$. Then
$$
\left\{\limsup_{n\to\infty}X_n\ge t\right\}=\left\{\inf_{n\ge 1}\{Y_n\}\ge t\right\}=\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\{Y_n\ge t\}\supseteq \bigcap_{n\ge 1}\bigcup_{m\ge n}\{X_m\ge t\}.
$$